How to set block device name using udev rules based on sdcard reader serial number
I have sdcard reader and I want to set block device names to /dev/sdcard2 and their partitions will be named /dev/sdcard2p1 /dev/sdcard2p2 /dev/sdcard2p3 ... (based on partition count of specific card inserted in reader)
This rule must apply to any sdcard (with various count of partitions) inserted in this specific sdcard reader (distinguished by serial number) and block devices pointing to inserted sdcard must have those names.
Sdcard reader has this serial number  ID_SERIAL_SHORT=20210500010790
So I want to write udev rule which will set block device name as I described above.
I tried this rule:
KERNEL=="sd*", ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="20210500010790", SYMLINK+="sdcard2%n"

But it is not working, what I am doing wrong?
This is output of udevadm monitor --environment --udev: pastebin
Update: I found some solution:
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTRS{serial}=="20210500010790", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", SYMLINK+="sdcard2"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTRS{serial}=="20210500010790", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition", SYMLINK+="sdcard2p%n"

It works with ATTRS, but it does not work with ENV, but why?

@TOmaas did you reload the rules?  ùdevadm control -R, cant see a mistake!

Yes I did reload. But I found some solution, it works with  ATTRS{serial}=="20210500010790" instead of ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="20210500010790"
